# Using an eq matcher with java.lang.UUID in Specs2 Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

We recently changed the API on one of our services, it used to be:

`def updateSubtitle(subtitleId: String...): Subtitle`

Now it is:

`def updateSubtitle(subtitleId: UUID, ...): Subtitle`

And previously we wrote our expectations like so:

`there was one(subtitleService).updateSubtitle(eq(subtitleId), ...)`

This won't work anymore because `subtitleId` is now a `UUID` instead of a `String`.  I've had to change `eq(subtitleId)` to `any[UUID]` however this is too generic as it doesn't actually test for the `subtitleId` value, it only cares that a value of type `UUID` was passed.

How can I get an `eq` matcher to work with `UUID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eq(subtitleId)` does work with `UUID` because the `UUID.equals` method is correctly implemented (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#equals(java.lang.Object).

You may be having issues with the naming clash between `scala.AnyRef.eq` and `org.mockito.Matchers.eq` (see https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/361). This can be solved by either:

- Fully referencing the `Matchers.eq` (i.e. `one(subtitleService).updateSubtitle(org.mockito.Matchers.eq(subtitleId), ...)`) or
- Using Scala import aliases to change the `Matchers.eq` name (i.e. `import org.mockito.Matchers.{eq => meq, _}` and changing your matcher use accordingly to `meq(subtitleId)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll bet you that is the case!  I'll give it a try and see